# Group by and replace

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table like that :

```
groupe  subgroup    id  status
A          a       1    up
A          b       1    notdefined
A          c       1    null
A          a       2    up
A          b       2    up
A          c       2    up
A          a       3    up
A          b       3    up
A          c       3    null
```

What I need is that for each combination (group-id) return a specified status
if for each (group,id) there is a status with notdefined return the global status as notdefined

if all status = up return global status = up
if there is up  but there is a null return notspecified

so the result should be like that

```
Groupe      id      global_status
A            1       notdefined
A            2        up
A            3        notspecified
```

I've tried something on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f5c6/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [boolean aggregates:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select 
   groupe, 
   id, 
   case 
      when bool_and(status = 'up') then 'up' 
      when bool_or(status = 'notdefined') then 'notdefined' 
      else 'notpecified' 
   end as status
from tab
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f5c6/16)

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and conditional logic:

```
select groupe, id,
       (case when count(*) filter (where status = 'notdefined') > 0
             then 'notdefined'
             when count(*) filter (where status is null) > 0
             then 'notspecified'
             when max(status) = min(status) and min(status) = 'up'
             then 'up'
             else 'something else'
        end) as global_status
from t
group by groupe, id;
```